# Doctrine relation from MappedSuperClass to Entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I want to ultimately have an abstract base class that defines a relationship to another entity for all inheriting Entity-classes. So have this test-setup that was created with symfony's *make:entity*-command.
The only thing I changed was switching the MappedSuperClass's property-visibility from private to protected to make them visible to the extenders.

This is the MappedSuperClass:

```
[...]

/**
 * Class TestMappedSuperclass
 *
 * @package App\Entity
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass()
 */
class TestMappedSuperclass
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=TestTarget::class, mappedBy="testMappedSuperclass")
     */
    protected $targets;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->targets = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    //..getters/setters,add/remove...
}
```

This my target-entity for the mapping:

```
[...]    
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=TestTargetRepository::class)
 */
class TestTarget
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=TestMappedSuperclass::class, inversedBy="targets")
     */
    private $testMappedSuperclass;

    // ..getters,setters..
}
```

This is the extending entity class:

```
[...]
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=TestEntityRepository::class)
 */
class TestEntity extends TestMappedSuperclass
{
}
```

So when I try to do a *make:migration* it produces the following error:

```
Column name `id` referenced for relation from App\Entity\TestTarget towards 
App\Entity\TestMappedSuperclass does not exist.
```

Using: Symfony 5.1, Doctrine 2.7

Comment: You cannot have a bidirectional relationship in a MappedSuperClass, nor have it as a relation target, since it's not an Entity.

Comment: Now that's unfortunate...it seems pretty counterintuitive having to declare the relationship in every extending class. Thanks for the answer nonetheless!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you need to have repeat id as protected in TestEntity :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=TestEntityRepository::class)
 */
class TestEntity extends TestMappedSuperclass
{
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
}
```

I took this from a project where i´m using mappedSuperClass like this, i´m not relate entities in it though

Comment: Unfortunately nothing changes :/